# Function value in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found the following exercise in a set theory book.

Let $f(x)$ denote $\bigcup \left\{y : \langle x,y\rangle \in f\right\}$.

Prove that for any function $f$ and $x\in  \mathsf{dom}(f)$  we have:
\begin{equation}
\langle x,y\rangle \in  f\leftrightarrow  y = f(x)
\end{equation}

As I undertand it, being $f$ a function, there is a single $y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle \in f$, hence  the union is $\left\{z : z=y \right\}$, abbreviated by $\left\{y \right\}$.

What I get is  therefore   $\left\{y \right\}= f(x)$ rather then $y = f(x)$.

Comment: Your notation is incorrect.  The function value is y.  {y} is the set containing y, not the value itself.

Comment: @user247327: What notation, please?  Here $f(x)=y$ is what I should prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're computing $\{y:\left <x,y\right> \in f\}$, not $\bigcup\{y:\left <x,y\right> \in f\}$.

Since (correctly) $\{y:\left <x,y\right> \in f\}=\{f(x)\}$ then $$\bigcup\{y:\left <x,y\right> \in f\} = \bigcup\{f(x)\} = f(x)$$ because $\bigcup\{A\}=A$ in general.

Comment: I think I understood my problem: there are no urelements/atoms in the range of $f$. With atoms: $$f(x) = \bigcup \left\{y : \langle x,y\rangle \in f\right\} = \bigcup\{y\} =\emptyset$$  without: $$f(x) = \bigcup \left\{y : \langle x,y\rangle \in f\right\} = \bigcup\{y\}  = y$$ where $y$ is the one (unique) in $\langle x,y\rangle$. So it should not work with atoms, unless one redefines $f(x)$ accordingly.

Comment: @antonio: Correct: the definition works only in the usual style of _hereditary_ set theory, where all elements of a set are themselves sets.